inverse limits of epimorphisms in (nuclear) TVS
Definition (Bidirected set)
A directed set $(I,\leq)$ is said to be bidirected, if $(I,\geq)$ is also a directed set.
Definition(Preserved property)
Let $\mathcal C$ be a category and $P$ a property of morphisms (for example, epimorphisms). We say that $P$ is preserved under inverse limits, if the following holds.
Let $A_{ij}:A_i\to A_j$ for $j\leq i\in I$ be any inverse system over a directed set $I$ in $\mathcal C$. Assume that each of the $A_{ij}$ has the property $P$. Then the maps from the limit $\varprojlim A_j\to A_i$ also have property $P$. We say that it is preserved under bilimits if it is preserved under inverse limits indexed by a bidirected set.
What I am truly interested in is the case where $\mathcal C$ is the category of (reflexive) nuclear spaces and $P$ is the property of epimorphism, that is, a continuous linear map with dense image. Is it true that $P$ is preserved under (bi) inverse limits?
More relaxed question - is there any property that either extends epimorphicity or generalizes epimorphicity that is preserved under (bi) inverse limits?
I would be happy if it were true for general limits and not only directed ones. This might actually be the case, since general products are inverse limits of finite products, which are all nuclear, and subspaces are also nuclear, so I would not be surprised that if it is true for (directed) inverse limits it would be true for general limits.
You may assume whatever extra reasonable assumptions on the maps $A_{ij}$, say, they are monomorphisms, and satisfy the following property $Q$:

for $i,j\in I$ and $f:E\to A_i$ linear such that $A_{ij}\circ f$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

Lemma
The property $Q$ is preserved under bilimits.
proof:
Let $A=\varprojlim A_j$ be the limit, and let $a_i:A\to A_i$ be the projections. We prove that $a_i$ is $Q$. Let $f:B\to A$ be a linear map such that $a_i\circ f$ is continuous. For $j\in I$, let $k\in I$ be such that $k\leq i,j$, which exists since we assume $I$ is bidirected. Then
$$
a_{ik}\circ a_i\circ f=a_k\circ f=a_{jk}\circ a_j\circ f
$$
is continuous. Since $a_{jk}$ is $Q$, we get that $a_j\circ f$ is continuous. Since this is true for all $j$, by the universal property of the inverse limit in Top, we get there is some continuous $\tilde f:B\to A$ such that $a_j\circ f=a_j\circ \tilde f$ for all $j\in I$. Since $f,\tilde f$ are linear, by the universal property of the inverse limit in Vec, we get that $\tilde f=f$, so $f$ is continuous. Thus, $a_i$ is $Q$. This ends the proof.
I searched the entire internet but could not find any references. I know that generally a pullback of an epimorphism need not be an epimorphism, at least in some categories. I am looking for reasonable conditions, however strict, or a new property of morphisms that includes epimorphisms, so that inverse limits preserve this property, in the sense described above.

For (inverse) limits of Banach spaces it is not true that surjectivity of all $a_{i,j}$ implies surjectivity of the limit morphisms. An example is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158761/tietzes-extension-theorem-for-compact-subspaces

Thanks. However, note that I am looking at morphisms with dense image, rather than surjective, and on nuclear spaces, rather than Banach spaces.

No reaction to my answer?

I think you can make a counterexample from the example I mentioned in the comment: Let $X$ be a topological space which is compactly generated and all real-valued continuous functions are constant (e.g., the irrational slope topology). For the set $I$ of compact subsets directed by inclusion and $K\in I$ let $C(K)$ be the space a real-valued continuous functions not endowed with its natural Banach space topology but with the weak topology $\sigma(C(K),C(K)^*)$ which makes it a nuclear locally convex space. For $K\subseteq L\in I$, the restriction $C(L)\to C(K)$ is surjective and hence has dense range but the restriction from the (inverse) limit $C(X)$ to $C(K)$ has one-dimensional image which is not dense.

You certainly know the Mittag-Leffler principle saying that for a countable limit of complete metric spaces where all linking maps have dense range also the limit morphisms have dense range (this is a theorem of Richard Arens from 1958).
There are versions beyond metrizability (in a locally convex setting) where density has to be replaced by stronger assumptions. However, Arens's theorem does not hold for non-metrizable nuclear spaces:
My answer to this question contains an example of an inductive system of nuclear Fréchet spaces $F_n\subseteq F_{n+1}$ (with continuous injective inclusions) such that the locally convex inductive limit $F$ (=colimit in the category of locally convex spaces) has the trivial (coarsest) topology.
The strong duals $X_n=F_n'$ are nuclear with dense restrictions (this follows from Hahn-Banach and the injectivity of the inclusions) but the limit morphisms $F'\to F_n'$ do not have dense range (because $F'=\{0\}$).

Thank you very much, this is making things much clearer! Is it obvious that the dual of the colimit is the limit of the duals? Do you know anything about finite limits that are not directed?

That the dual of a colimit is the limit of the duals is the universal property of colimits.

Right, of course. Thank you!
